# Serving binary file from web server to client

Tags: python, content-type

Usually, when I want to transfer a web server text file to client, here is what I did

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.txt"
print

filename = "C:\\TEST.TXT"
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

Works very fine for ANSI file. However, say, I have a binary file `a.exe` (This file is in web server secret path, and user shall not have direct access to that directory path). I wish to use the similar method to transfer. How I can do so?

- What content-type I should use?
- Using print seems to have corrupted content received at client side. What is the correct method?

I use the following code.

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

import cgi

print "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=jstock.exe"
print

filename = "C:\\jstock.exe"
f = open(filename, 'rb')
for line in f:
    print line
```

However, when I compare the downloaded file with original file, it seems there is an extra whitespace (or more) for after every single line.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with the above posters about 'rb' and Content-Type headers.

Additionally:

```
for line in f:
    print line
```

This might be a problem when encountering `\n` or `\r\n` bytes in the binary file. It might be better to do something like this:

```
import sys
while True:
    data = f.read(4096)
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    if not data:
        break
```

Assuming this is running on windows in a CGI environment, you will want to start the python process with the `-u` argument, this will ensure stdout isn't in text-mode

Answer (score 2):

When opening a file, you can use `open(filename, 'rb')` - the 'b' flag marks it as binary. For a general handler, you could use some form of mime magic (I'm not familiar with using it from Python, I've only ever used it from PHP a couple of years ago). For the specific case, `.exe` is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I edited my question to show there is additional problem found beside 'b' flag and content-type.

Comment: The others are right about not using `print` but instead using `sys.stdout.write` (I had been going to mention it but forgot). I won't bother updating my answer to list that.

Answer (score 1):

Content-type of `.exe` is tipically `application/octet-stream`.
You might want to read your file using `open(filename, 'rb')` where `b` means binary.

To avoid the whitespace problem, you could try with:

```
sys.stdout.write(open(filename,"rb").read())
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or even better, depending on the size of your file, use the [Knio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517134/transferring-binary-file-from-web-server-to-client/4517294#4517294) approach:

```
fo = open(filename, "rb")
while True:
    buffer = fo.read(4096)
    if buffer:
        sys.stdout.write(buffer)
    else:
        break
fo.close()
```

Comment: I edited my question to show there is additional problem found beside 'b' flag and content-type.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Windows Server 2008 or 2012 and Python 3, here's an update...

After many hours of experimentation I have found the following to work reliably:

```
import io

with io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(),"wb") as fout:
    with open(filename,"rb") as fin:
        while True:
            data = fin.read(4096)
            fout.write(data)
            if not data:
                break
```